# Swift equivalent of Ruby’s Concurrent::Event?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, concurrency

The popular Concurrent-Ruby library has a [`Concurrent::Event` class](https://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/master/Concurrent/Event.html) that I find wonderful. It very neatly encapsulates the idea of, “Some threads need to wait for another thread to finish something before proceeding.”

It only takes three lines of code to use:

- One to create the object
- One to call `.wait` to start waiting, and
- One to call `.set` when the thing is ready.

All the locks and booleans you’d need to use to create this out of other concurrency primitives are taken care of for you.

To quote some of the documentation, along with with a sample usage:

> Old school kernel-style event reminiscent of Win32 programming in C++.
>
> When an `Event` is created it is in the `unset` state. Threads can choose to
> `#wait` on the event, blocking until released by another thread. When one
> thread wants to alert all blocking threads it calls the `#set` method which
> will then wake up all listeners. Once an `Event` has been set it remains set.
> New threads calling `#wait` will return immediately.
>
> ```
> require 'concurrent-ruby'
>
> event = Concurrent::Event.new
>
> t1 = Thread.new do
>   puts "t1 is waiting"
>   event.wait
>   puts "event ocurred"
> end
>
> t2 = Thread.new do
>   puts "t2 calling set"
>   event.set
> end
>
> [t1, t2].each(&:join)
> ```

which prints output like the following

```
t1 is waiting
t2 calling set
event occurred
```

(Several different orders are possible because it is multithreaded, but ‘t2 calling set’ always comes out before ‘event occurred’.)

---

Is there something like this in Swift on iOS?

Comment: This is similar to using dispatching work on a parallel dispatch queue, coordinated by a disoatch group. But this isn’t a very fun pattern to use though, it’s really low-level and error prone. You’re better off using observable/publishers from RxSwift/Combine

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the result in your example using a Grand Central Dispatch [DispatchSemaphore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsemaphore) - This is a traditional counting semaphore.  Each call to `signal` increments the semaphore.  Each call to `wait` decrement the semaphore and if the result is less than zero it blocks and waits until the semaphore is 0

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

let q1 = DispatchQueue(label:"q1", target: .global(qos: .utility))

let q2 = DispatchQueue(label:"q2", target: .global(qos: .utility))

q1.async {
   print("q1 is waiting")
   semaphore.wait()
   print("event occurred")
}

q2.async {
   print("q2 calling signal")
   semaphore.signal()
}
```

Output:

> q1 is waiting
>
> q2 calling signal
>
> event occurred

But this object won't work if you have multiple threads that want to wait. Since each call to `wait` decrements the semaphore the other tasks would remain blocked.

For that you could use a [`DispatchGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup).  You call `enter` before you start a task in the group and `leave` when it is done.  You can use `wait` to block until the group is empty, and like your Ruby object, `wait` will not block if the group is already empty and multiple threads can `wait` on the same group.

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

let q1 = DispatchQueue(label:"q1", target: .global(qos: .utility))

let q2 = DispatchQueue(label:"q2", target: .global(qos: .utility))

q1.async {
    print("q1 is waiting")
    group.wait()
        print("event occurred")
}

group.enter()
q2.async {
    print("q2 calling leave")
    group.leave()
}
```

Output:

> q1 is waiting
>
> q2 calling leave
>
> event occurred

You generally want to avoid blocking threads on iOS if possible as there is a risk of deadlocks and if you block the main thread your whole app will become non responsive.  It is more common to use `notify` to schedule code to execute when the group becomes empty.

I understand that your code is simply a contrived example, but depending on what you actually want to do and your minimum supported iOS requirements, there may be better alternatives.

- DispatchGroup to execute code when several asynchronous tasks are complete using `notify` rather than `wait`
- Combine to process asynchronous events in a pipeline (iOS 13+)
- Async/Await (iOS 15+)

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest thing to that is the new `async/await` syntax in Swift 5.5. There's no equivalent of `event.set`, but `await` waits for something asynchronous to finish. A particularly nice expression of concurrency is `async let`, which proceeds concurrently but then lets you pause to gather up all the results of the `async let` calls:

```
async let result1 = // do something asynchronous
async let result2 = // do something else asynchronous at the same time
// ... and keep going...
// now let's gather up the results
return await (result1, result2)
```